# How to set default value on dynamic input fields in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a dynamic input fields but the problem is that I don't know how to set default values on that dynamic fields for example number "1". Can anyone help me with that? Thanks

Here is my example

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    result: [],
    array: [{
     id: 1
    }, {
     id: 2
    }, {
     id: 3
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in array" :key="item.id">
    <input type="number" :id="item.id" v-model="result[index]">
    <br>
  </div>
  <span>Result: {{ result }}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post some part of code in here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Vue js is reactive you can simply set initial value in result

```
 new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        result: ["1","1","1"],
        array: [{
            id: 1
        }, {
            id: 2
        }, {
            id: 3
        }]
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html),

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes
> found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data
> as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the
> JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.

I think it is a design decision of Vue to use the benefit of Vue instance’s reactive system rather than listening to DOM updates when such attributes are updated.

So you can put directly your default values into the `result` array, here's the updated working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78gboL9z/13/).